# Ask - How to add multiple List<T> to List<T> with a specific name

Tags: c#, list, generics, arraylist

If I have a `list<T>` like this :

```
    private void aVariant()
    {
        List<Variant> variant = new List<Variant>();
        variant.Add(new Variant() { name = "a", optionID });
        variant.Add(new Variant() { name = "b", optionID });
    }
```

how to add the following multiple `<optionID>` to the above list, if :

name = "a" :

```
    List<OptionID> optionID = new List<OptionID>();
    optionID.Add(new OptionID() { id = "123black", value = "black" });
    optionID.Add(new OptionID() { id = "123red", value = "red" });
```

and for name = "b"

```
    List<OptionID> optionID = new List<OptionID>();
    optionID.Add(new OptionID() { id = "456S", value = "S" });
    optionID.Add(new OptionID() { id = "456M", value = "M" });
```

Update, for the class section like this :

```
public class GetData
{
    public List<Variant> variant { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<OptionID> optionID { get; set; }
}

public class OptionID
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can try to add a property to the Variant class. `public List<OptionID> optionID { get; set; }`

Comment: So the `optionID` in `Variant` class is a `List<>` ?

Comment: What is type of `optionID` in `Variant` class?

Comment: @KyleWang, i already have it

Comment: Can you post `Variant` class?

Comment: @ParsaFat'hollahi, please see my update

Comment: @Kolimondi So did you try `variant.Add(new Variant() { name = "a", optionID = optionIDofa});    variant.Add(new Variant() { name = "b", optionID = optionIDofb});`?

Comment: @KyleWang, can't, unless the optionID type is "list string"

Comment: @Kolimondi Please refer to the answer demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works fine in my test.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<OptionID> optionIDofa = new List<OptionID>();
        optionIDofa.Add(new OptionID() { id = "123black", value = "black" });
        optionIDofa.Add(new OptionID() { id = "123red", value = "red" });

        List<OptionID> optionIDofb = new List<OptionID>();
        optionIDofb.Add(new OptionID() { id = "456S", value = "S" });
        optionIDofb.Add(new OptionID() { id = "456M", value = "M" });

        List<Variant> variant = new List<Variant>();
        variant.Add(new Variant() { name = "a", optionID = optionIDofa });
        variant.Add(new Variant() { name = "b", optionID = optionIDofb });
    }

}

public class Variant
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<OptionID> optionID { get; set; }
}

public class OptionID
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```